# Prove that any PDA/CF language with 1 character is regular

Tags: formal-languages, regular-languages, context-free, pushdown-automata

I know there is a post like this already posted, but I didn't quite understand the proof. Can someone explain it to me? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you link to that post?

Comment: Can you explain what you don't understand? Some results are just difficult to prove, and there's not much that can be done about it.

Comment: https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/40791/proving-that-any-cf-language-over-a-1-letter-alphabet-is-regular Here is the post. I understood everything that the person who asked the question said, but could not quite understand what the accepted answer is trying to say.

Comment: Added a new and detailed answer to the original post. It's best to keep all answers at the same place.