# CFL with regular substitution to make a regular language

Tags: regular-languages, automata, finite-automata, context-free

If I have a CFL, can I define a regular substitution to make it a RL?

For example, if I have the language $\{a^nb^n \mid n\ge0\}:$

Define $h(a)=a$ , $h(b)=b$, then $h(L)={a^*}$ , am I right?

Thanks!

Comment: Please don't double post. When you ask a question on a site, it is simple courtesy to give that community the opportunity to answer it. It's true that this site is a better fit for [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72614882/cfl-with-regular-substitution-to-make-a-regular-language) but if you decide that your question should have been posted on a different site, you should either request migration (if it has already been answered) or delete it from the original site.

Answer (score 1):

No,by your defined substitution CFLs remains CFLs.
For example, $\{a^nb^n \mid n\ge0\} = \{\epsilon,ab, aabb, aaabbb,.......\}.$
After substitution by $h(a) = a$ and $h(b) =b$,$h(\epsilon) = \epsilon$  then the language L becomes remains same, which is CFL. But when every symbol converges to single image then your language forcefully becomes regular (as @rici answer) which is really very bad way of thinking because by the definition homomorphism of CFLs is CFLs.

N. B.- One thing remember substitution for DCFLs are not closed in general [(for example)](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/11792/deterministic-cfl-closure-property-homomorphism) but substitution for CFLs(NCFLs) are closed always.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can.

For instance: with language $L = \{a^nb^n \mid n\ge0\}$
and mapping $h(\epsilon)=\epsilon, h(a)=a, h(b)=a$ (which I think is what you meant to write), $h(L) = (aa)^*$.

What is more: [*every* context-free language on a single-symbol alphabet is regular](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/40791/proving-that-any-cf-language-over-a-1-letter-alphabet-is-regular), so a mapping that maps every symbol to the same symbol always produces a regular language.

However, as user19121278 points out, not every mapping will.

For instance: the identity mapping ($h(\epsilon)=\epsilon, h(a)=a, h(b)=b$ for alphabet $\{a,b\}$) maps every language to itself, so it will never map a non-regular language onto a regular one.